# changing mnemonic changes address

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, machine-code

I'm new to gdb and assembly. I'm trying to change the mnemonic instruction from `jg` to `jle`, but whenever I change the mnemonic, it also changes the destination address. For example,

Let's say I'm trying to modify this one:

```
4005a5 0f 8f 1e 01 00 00 jg 400c74 <Function_1>
```

So, I did

```
$set *0x4005a5 = 0x7e
```

Then, what happens is it changes the 400c74 to some random address, like 400ae4.
I thought it might be the issue of short jump and near jump,
so I even did `= 0x0f8e` `= 0x74400c7e` `= 0x0f8e400c74` so on.

But, they are all changing the jump to location..

Can anyone explain why this is happening, please?

Comment: Can you show the disassembly afterward from GDB?  I'm not sure of the default size for `set`, it might be overwriting multiple bytes.  And x86 is little-endian, so `0x0f8e` is not `0f 8e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`set *(unsigned short*)0x4005a5 = 0x8e0f`**

---

2 problems I think:

- `set *0x4005a5 = 0x7e` probably defaults to a dword store, writing 4 bytes instead of 1.
- And you got the opcode wrong 2 different ways: short vs. near, and then an endian issue for the near.

---

Yes, the original instruction is using the [Near encoding (`jcc rel32`)](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html), where the opcode is 2 bytes `0f 8f`.  You can tell because the full instruction is 6 bytes long instead of 2, and starts with `0f` (so it's not a single-byte opcode.)

You're replacing it with a 1-byte Short `jle rel8`, so the 2nd opcode byte becomes the rel8.

(Original 8086 only has `jcc rel8` for conditional jumps, with only unconditional jumps like `jmp` having both a rel8 and rel16 encoding; somewhere between 186 and 386 the `jcc rel16/rel32` encoding was added.)

---

Your attempt to set `0x0f8e` has an endian problem.  **x86 is little-endian, so `jle`'s opcode `0F 8E` as a little-endian `unsigned short` has the value `0x8e0f`.**

`8E` is the opcode for [`mov Sreg, r/m16`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html), so `0x0f8e` (`8E 0F`) will decode as a mov to a segment reg, with `0F` as the ModR/M byte.  Use GDB to disassemble the instruction after modifying it.

Use GDB's `disas /r` to disassemble with raw hex as well as mnemonics.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response! I tried with the jle rel32, which is 0x0F8E, but it still changes the address... Could there be any other reasons? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much.. It's unsigned short that solved everything... Thank you very much for spending the time to solve this mystery! I've learnt something valuable from you.